# Difference between an endpoint and a port in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, network, terminology, configuration-manager

While I know why are ports used in SQL Server, I wonder what is the difference between an endpoint and a port. Ports can be managed using Configuration Manager, is it also possible to manage endpoints with CM?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think of it as the endpoint being the "SQL Server side" part of what a client connects to. There are endpoints for TCP (probably the one you refer to), Named Pipes and Shared Memory. Those are the regular endpoints that a client application connects to. You can, for instance, set privileges on an endpoint, allowing login A to connect to TCP and B connect to Shared Memory (not that I've ever had the need for this). The endpoint is implemented by a DLL (I usually refer to all this as "NetLib", and for TCP and Named Pipes exposed through a port.

Then there are endpoints for mirroring and the old SOAP web-methods as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does it mean that each port has its appropriate endpoint, which helps to connect clients to a specified port??

Comment: I'm not sure I'd phrase it that way. A part of the endpoint is the port number. The endpoint is also manageable, in the sense that you can define permissions on it (and for other type of endpoints change port number).